# bit.ly Clone in Python powered by Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Recently, I was studying flask and my friend sent me a bit.ly link. Then the idea of a bit.ly clone struck my mind.

This project uses

- Python - 3.10.0
- flask - version 2.0.2
- Bootstrap CSS. (I am very bad at CSS)
- sqlite3

I would appreciate you thoughts and improvements on my implementation.

File directory structure -

```
Bit.ly Clone -
              |- templates -
                            | - index.html
              |- app.py
              |- database.db
              |- schema.sql
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Url Shortener</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Url Shortener</h1>

    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="URL">URL</label>
              <input name="org_url" class="form-control" id="URL">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="short_url">Short URL</label>
              <input name="short_url" class="form-control" id="short_url">
        </div> <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS URL_Table;

CREATE TABLE URL_Table (
    org_url TEXT NOT NULL,
    short_url TEXT NOT NULL);
```

### database.db

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
database = 'database.db'

def init_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open('schema.sql', 'r') as file:
        cursor.executescript(file.read())
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def get_db_conn():
    return sqlite3.connect(database)

def get_record(short_url):
    conn = get_db_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    record = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM URL_Table WHERE short_url = ?', (short_url,)).fetchone()
    conn.close()

    return record

def create_record(org_url, short_url):
    conn = get_db_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO URL_Table VALUES(?, ?)', (org_url, short_url))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    init_db()
    return redirect('/create')

@app.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_record(request.form['org_url'], request.form['short_url'])
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<string:url>')
def get_url(url):
    record = get_record(url)
    if record is None:
        return abort(404)
    return redirect(record[0])

app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks!